# How to place an image above the header using shinydashboard

Tags: r, image, shiny, header, shinydashboard

I want to put an image on top of the header of my shiny app using [shinydashboard](/questions/tagged/shinydashboard) just like shown below but I don't know how to approach this issue.

[image: Example]

Here is the basic [dashboard structure](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply wrap the `dashboardPage` in a `body` tag and include the image:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- tags$body(
  tags$img(src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqerJ.png", width = '100%'),
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Relevant info:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/660

Here is another way to realize this:
https://jonkatz2.github.io/2018/06/22/Image-In-Shinydashboard-Header

PS: you might want to save that image in your local `www` folder instead of using imgur.com as the `src`.

Comment: When I get 15 reputation I will, thank you again

Comment: @NandroKeiko accepting an answer can be done regardless of your reputation score.