# How to place elements above the dashboardHeader

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm a beginner in Shiny and I'm looking to develop my first app. I'm having difficulty because I would like to add a top header bar to my dashboard, with a logo and the name of my study group on the upper left side of the page, and on the right side, a "Stop App" button. I would appreciate some help in achieving this page configuration like in the image.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My first app"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap the `dashboardPage` in a body-tag to achive this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- tags$body(
  tags$img(src = "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.svg", width = '60px'),
  tags$span("My Team Name", style = "margin-left:25px;"),
  actionButton("mybutton", "My Button", icon = icon("plus"), style = "float:right; margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px"),
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73134097/9841389) you can find a related answer.